# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(MyComponent)" ? Redux-React Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build my first small web application using redux and react, I am following a course and doing exactly what he does so I can learn how to set things, But I get an error in my console :

```
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(UserList)"
```

Now I will explain what I have done, I made this simple folder structure :

```
reactapp --- src --- actions ( empty for now )

                 --- components --- app.js
                                --- userlist.js

                 --- reducers   --- index.js
                                --- userlist.js

                 index.js
```

Here is my smiple reducers/userlist file :

```
export default function() {
  return [
    { id: 1, nom: "Taoufiq BENALLAH", active: "NON", role: "Internship" },
    { id: 2, nom: "Mounia Drari", active: "OUI", role: "Developer" },
    { id: 3, nom: "Jaouhar Alaoui", active: "NON", role: "Internship" },
    { id: 4, nom: "ILyass LAZ", active: "OUI", role: "Technical Expert" }
  ];
}
```

And that is my reducers/index.js file : ( my importation are set right )

```
import { combineReducer } from "redux";
import UserList from "./userlist";

const rootReducer = function() {
   users: UserList;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

That is my components userlist :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class UserList extends Component {
   render() {
     return <div>{this.props.users}</div>;
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
     users: state.users
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

here is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserList from "./userlist";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and Finally that is my src/index.js as usual :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./components/app";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Here is my error again in details : 
    [image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You need to wrap App in Provider and add store as props in index.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap in `Provider` and add store as props. Please see [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/Provider.md#example-usage). In app.js:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <div>
    <UserList />
  </div>
</Provider>
```